# Why do I keep on getting No module named: official error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I am trying to train an  object detection model in google colab using some custom dataset but when ever I execute this bit of code:

```
    %cd /content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/
    !python model_builder_test.py
```

I get the following error:

```
     2020-08-17 07:32:58.162622: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
            from object_detection.builders import model_builder
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 65, in <module>
            from object_detection.models import ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor as ssd_efficientnet_bifpn
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/models/ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 33, in <module>
            from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official'
```

I have added the path to the module official using os.eviron and sys.path.append but still the error persist .The following is my code:

```
          %tensorflow_version 1.x

           import tensorflow as tf
    device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
    if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
       raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
    print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
    print(tf.__version__)

    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
    !cd '/content/gdrive/My Drive/'

    !git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

    !apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
    !pip install Cython
    !pip install tf_slim

    %cd '/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research'
    !protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

    import os
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += '/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/:/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/slim'
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ":/content/gdrive/My drive/models"
    import sys
    sys.path.append(":/content/gdrive/My drive/models")
    !export PYTHONPATH='$PYTHONPATH:/content/gdrive/My Drive/models'
    
    !python setup.py build
    !python setup.py install

    import time, psutil
    Start = time.time()- psutil.boot_time()
    Left= 12*3600 - Start
    print('Time remaining for this session is: ', Left/3600)
    
    %cd '/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/slim'
    !python setup.py build
    !python setup.py install

    %cd /content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/object_detection/builders/
    !python model_builder_test.py
```

I believe that if the path of the folder in which the module is given then the program should be able to find it.But some how the program cannot find the module.
I also once mistakely added a wrong path in the pythonpath which does not exist is that why this problem persist?

```
/env/python/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/:/content/gdrive/My Drive/Desktop/models/research/slim:/content/gdrive/My drive/models/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/:/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/slim:/content/gdrive/My drive/models/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/:/content/gdrive/My Drive/models/research/slim:/content/gdrive/My drive/models
```

The path "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Desktop/models/research/slim" does not exist, Is this the problem?

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

```
!apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
!pip install Cython tf_slim
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
%cd /content/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
%set_env PYTHONPATH=/content/models/research:/content/models/research/slim
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ":/content/models"
import sys
sys.path.append("/content/models")
!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

OR TRY

```
../models/research pip install tf-models-official
```